# Show $\lambda$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to ${\rm Aut}(L^{\infty}(G))$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group. Define the left translation:

$\lambda:G \to {\rm Aut}(L^{\infty}(G))$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$  given by $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $(\lambda_{g} \varphi)(x)=\varphi(g^{-1}x)$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ for $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $\varphi \in L^{\infty}(G)$

Show that $\lambda$ is a well defined group homomorphism.

I'm really confused by what $\lambda$ is in this question. Its a function from $G$ to the group of Automorphisms of $L^{\infty}(G)$, but then its not defined to be a function on an element of $G$. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this function to me!

Comment: The function sends $g$ to $\lambda_g$, which is an automorphism of $L^\infty(G)$. The displayed formula is defining $\lambda_g$ by saying where it sends an element $\varphi \in L^\infty(G)$: namely to the function $\lambda_g \varphi$ defined by the given formula.

Comment: $\lambda$ *is* defined as a function on $G$ but you might not see it right away because of the notation. We can alternatively write $\lambda(g) \in {\rm Aut}(L^{\infty}(G))$ for all $g \in G$. Now how does $\lambda(g)$ act on $\phi \in L^{\infty}(G)$? It's just as in the equation in your question except $g$ is written in the subscript. It's just a choice of notation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, that makes sense now, it was just the notation that was confusing me!

Comment: @PratyushSarkar You should give an official answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ *is* defined as a function on $G$ but you might not see it right away because of the notation. We can alternatively write $\lambda(g) \in \mathrm{Aut}(L^\infty(G))$ for all $g \in G$. Now, how does $\lambda(g)$ act on $\phi \in L^\infty(G)$? It's just as in the equation in your question except $g$ is written in the subscript. It's just a choice of notation.